# How to get each db result value count

Tags: database

How to get values count in db_select
My query is:

```
$last_item = '2015-07-19';
$query = db_select('field_data_appointment_date','ap');
$query->join('field_data_appointment_slot','aps','aps.entity_id = ap.entity_id');
$query->fields('aps',array('appointment_slot_value '));
$query->condition('ap.appointment_date_value', '%' . db_like($last_item) . '%', 'LIKE');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
dsm($result);
```

and my result is:

```
... (Array, 4 elements)
0 (Array, 1 element)
appointment_slot_value (String, 11 characters ) 10.00-11.00
1 (Array, 1 element)
appointment_slot_value (String, 11 characters ) 10.00-11.00
2 (Array, 1 element)
appointment_slot_value (String, 11 characters ) 10.00-11.00
3 (Array, 1 element)
appointment_slot_value (String, 11 characters ) 11.00-12.00
```

I need result like count of

```
:10.00-11.00 is 3
:11.00-12:00 is 1
```

Anyone help me out

Comment: What do you want to do? Give more details. maybe non straight query on Database solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding the output you really want to achieve, but here's examples on how to count the results coming from the database

[get count with db_select](https://www.drupal.org/node/1226410)

OR

[rowCount](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3ArowCount/7)

Let me know if any of those work for you.